# Calculating the ridge parameter for given ridge estimates

Tags: regression, response, linear-regression, lasso-regression

Suppose response and covariate data are below:

```
(1.4, 0.0), (1.4, -2.0), (0.8, 0.0), (0.4,2.0).
```

I want to find the ridge parameter k, for which the ridge estimates are `(1, -1/8)` by applying the penalty parameter to slope.